# ElementMatchers::isToString fails in ByteBuddy 1.11.1 when toString() is not defined; is the matching pattern I'm using correct?

Tags: byte-buddy

Scenario: I am creating a proxy class (`com.foo.bar.Proxy$Z`) that subclasses the class it proxies (`Z.class`) and wraps an instance of it.  (Pretty standard stuff.)

I have a `Matcher` that figures out what things are "business methods".  It doesn't really matter what it does, but let's say for this question that it does not match `toString`.

I'd like the following rules to apply in order:

- First, make it so that my proxy class' `toString` method will simply forward any `toString` invocation to the instance.
- Second, make it so that if a business method is invoked on an instance of my proxy class, it will get forwarded to the instance.  (This is the same rule as above; the first rule simply is very specific and ensures that even if business method matching excludes `toString`, it will get "picked up".)

These are very standard kinds of rules.

Here is some ByteBuddy "matching" code hopefully implementing this that I haven't changed in several versions of ByteBuddy.  I upgraded to the 1.11.1 version and this now suddenly fails in a way that suggests that the recommended matching patterns no longer work, or that I have misunderstood them somehow and have gotten lucky in the past.

Here is a reduced snapshot of the code:

```
/*...*/
// my own matcher; irrelevant here except that it comes "second"
.method(isBusinessMethod())

// straightforward ByteBuddy proxying pattern
.intercept(MethodCall.invokeSelf()
           .onMethodCall(MethodCall.invoke(named("proxied")))
           .withAllArguments())

// the problematic bit; this used to work
.method(isToString()) // from ElementMatchers

// same implementation strategy as above
.intercept(MethodCall.invoke(named("toString"))
           .onMethodCall(MethodCall.invoke(named("proxied"))));
```

This used to succeed.  Now I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: class com.foo.bar.Proxy$Z does not define exactly one virtual method or constructor for name(equals(toString)) but contained 0 candidates: []
        at net.bytebuddy.implementation.MethodCall$MethodLocator$ForElementMatcher.resolve(MethodCall.java:816)
```

My proxy class being generated (`com.foo.bar.Proxy$Z.class`) does not itself define a `toString()` method (that's why I'm using matchers here).  But `Z.class` from which it extends does define a `toString()` method.

If a caller gets an instance of the proxy class, and calls `toString()` on it, my expectation is that the `Z` instance that my `com.foo.bar.Proxy$Z` proxy instance houses and returns from its (`private`) `proxied()` method will have the invocation forwarded to it.

The [ByteBuddy tutorial](https://bytebuddy.net/#/tutorial) says:

> Byte Buddy organizes rules for overriding methods in a stack form. This means that whenever you register a new rule for overriding a method, ít is pushed on the top of this stack and is always applied first until a new rule is added which will then be of even higher priority.

It also says:

> Because of this organization, you should always register more specific method matchers last. Otherwise, any less specific method matcher that is registered afterwards might prevent rules that you defined before from being applied.

That's exactly what I'm trying to do above and that has worked in prior ByteBuddy versions.  Specifically:

- `isToString()` is tried first.  If it matches, then its corresponding `intercept` logic will be employed. My expectation is that it will *always* match (there is always a "reachable" `toString()` method, no matter what your proxy class extends from).
- `isBusinessMethod()` is tried second.  If it matches, then its corresponding `intercept` logic will be employed.

Have I misunderstood how this works?  Or did ByteBuddy 1.11.1 change the logic from version 1.11.0 and earlier?  If I've misunderstood, how did this work in the past?

Rafael mentions that he "changed the methods considered for the matcher to exclude the instrumented method itself".  In this case, I suppose that `Z::toString` is the instrumented method?  Perhaps this is too aggressive, as he suggests: the supertype (`Z.class`) of my proxy class (`com.foo.bar.Proxy$Z`) does, remember, define a `toString()` method.  Perhaps this change did not consider this case?

Answer (score 1):

I had changed the methods considered for the matcher to exclude the instrumented method itself. I did not think much of it, I thought this would never be the desired outcome of matching. Please consider the [changed code](https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy/blob/master/byte-buddy-dep/src/main/java/net/bytebuddy/implementation/MethodCall.java#L807), maybe my change was too short sighted?

Comment: Interesting. I'll take a look. I dimly recall having a conversation with you about some other aspect of this area earlier; let me see if I can find the link. {time passes} This is what I was thinking of; not sure if it's related; putting it here for posterity: https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy/issues/1006

Comment: I'll edit my question to better describe what I want or expect to happen, and then perhaps you can answer it with a general recipe?

Comment: OK, I have edited the question to better describe what I'm trying to accomplish. Perhaps there's a simpler way to do it.

Comment: One last edit; I believe your assessment is correct.  This would seem to be a relatively common case that the change doesn't permit. I'll file an issue now that I understand the problem more fully.

Comment: I've filed https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy/issues/1061

Comment: …and a PR to fix it: https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy/pull/1062